# Other alternatives to comment replies indentation?

Tags: readability, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hierarchical comments usability issues](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3864/hierarchical-comments-usability-issues)

What are the best options to highlight a reply to a comment ? I'm thinking 3 levels maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say that indentation are the best. Is there a reason why you don't want to do indenting?

But if that is not an option I could see borders being used. A thinker right border would cause a slight indentation. the deeper the comment the bigger the right border. See example below.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkFyZF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>