# Dropdown for simple and data tables with multiple levels of hierarchy

Tags: tables, dropdown, data-tables

I had some tables which just had one groupping, and the arrow (accordion-type) was working fine, and users understood perfectly.
(As for now, I was using option B/groupping1).

Now, we have to introduce double groupping, which means that arrows might not be as userfriendly/easy to understand as they were, and specially in that position.
What do you think works best, or do you have any other options in mind?

Thanks in advance

-its desktop based
-tables have just one or many columns, having to use scroll vertical and horizontally[image]

Data-table added for more info/context
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any alternative UI for tree structure?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/is-there-any-alternative-ui-for-tree-structure)

Comment: Thanks @Dipak, but it's not exactly the same. Im not asking for ways of visualizing differently a treestructure, but how to improve readability/usability in a tree structure data-table, having different levels.

Comment: I'm confused. I can see the tree but not the table. Do you have another image that shows the full UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution A for 2 groupings seems to be the most easily readable. The arrows can be more easily confusing than the + and - symbols. If I would rate the solutions, I could say A, C, B.

Another solution could be a tree structure with the folders as it shown in the next image:

[image: Folder structure]

This could be beneficial and easier understood because people are quite used to tree windows structure and they might feel very familiar with it.

Comment: Yeah option A (a hierarchy wich is basically the windows folder system) is propbably what Im going to implement. Thanks for the answer,